# too many values to unpack in a yield

Tags: python, runtime-error, yield

this is an exercise where Item is a class, and when I run testAll I have a valueError. The yield is suppose to return just 2 values, the content of 2 bags:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    testAll()
  File "/Downloads/L18_code.py", line 101, in testAll
    pset1,pset2=yieldAllCombos(items)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

def buildItems():
return [Item(n,v,w) for n,v,w in (('clock', 175, 10),
                                  ('painting', 90, 9),
                                  ('radio', 20, 4),
                                  ('vase', 50, 2),
                                  ('book', 10, 1),
                                  ('computer', 200, 20))]
def yieldAllCombos(items):
"""
Generates all combinations of N items into two bags, whereby each item is in one or
zero bags.

Yields a tuple, (bag1, bag2), where each bag is represented as a list of which item(s)
are in each bag.
"""
N = len(items)
# enumerate the 3**N possible combinations
for i in xrange(3**N):
    combo1 = []
    combo2 = []
    for j in xrange(N):
        # test bit jth of integer i
        if (i >> j) % 3 == 1:
            combo1.append(items[j])
        elif (i>>j) % 3 == 2:
            combo2.append(items[j])        
    yield(combo1,combo2)
def testAll():
    items = buildItems()
    pset1,pset2=yieldAllCombos(items)
```

Answer (score 3):

You `yield` two items at a time in your loop, so you have to catch two at a time:

```
for pset1, pset2 in yieldAllCombos(items):
    ...
```

Comment: I don't understand the yield? it is not like a return? What does the for pset1... do?

Comment: @user1347096: Read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Comment: This is a red herring. The issue isn't two at a time vs. one at a time, it's trying to unpack the entire iterator (full of pairs, but that doesn't matter) at once.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't understand generators and the `yield` statement at all, see [the Python Wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for a general overview.

The problem is that you're trying to assign the entire generator `yieldAllCombos(items)` to two variables. This only works if `yieldAllCombos` generates exactly two values, by calling `yield` exactly twice.

But that's not what `yieldAllCombos` generates. If you want to see what it does, just try this:

```
print(list(yieldAllCombos(items)))
```

You'll see that you got back a large list of 2-tuples, one for each time it calls `yield` in the loop. And this shouldn't be too surprising, since a function called `yieldAllCombos` ought to be giving you a lot of combos, right? If you wanted to unpack the whole thing, you'd have to unpack it into one variable for each 2-tuple in the list, not just two variables. But that's probably not what you want.

What you probably want to do is iterator over all of the 2-tuples, unpacking each one. So:

```
for pset1, pset2 in yieldAllCombos(items):
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is suggestion

```
def testAll():
    items = buildItems()
    gen=yieldAllCombos(items)
    for l in range(3**len(items)+0):
        pset = next(gen)
        pset1 = pset[0]
        pset2 = pset[1]
        print(str(len(pset1)) + '   ' + str(len(pset2)))
        for j in range(len(pset1)):
            print(str(pset1[j]))
        for k in range(len(pset2)):
            print(str(pset2[k]))
```

The above code will generate an output similar to the following

```
Pset 1 length : 4 Pset 2 length : 2
******** pset 1 ********
<painting, 90.0, 9.0>
<vase, 50.0, 2.0>
<book, 10.0, 1.0>
<computer, 200.0, 20.0>
******** pset 2 ********
<clock, 175.0, 10.0>
<radio, 20.0, 4.0>
```

**Reference**

- [class and object referencing in Python, not understanding how values are return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550124/class-and-object-referencing-in-python-not-understading-how-values-are-return/68681181#68681181)