# class and object referencing in Python, not understanding how values are returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

EDIT: This got flagged as a duplicate because of my asking about how to properly print a class item. That was part of my question yes, but I was more confused about the interaction of object instances and the way things are referenced in general.  This has been helpful. Also, I should have done it originally, but I've included MITx's (online mooc) solution for the 'bag' creation of the 0/1 knapsack problem I've been learning. It probably makes it more clear why they wrote the `class` and `buildItems` function as they did.

I've read a gazillion tutorials now to try to understand the object referencing and creation of class instances in python and can't figure out why I'm getting this particular output that I haven't seen.

I have this program snippet:

```
class Item(object):
     def __init__(self, n, v, w):
         self.name = n
         self.value = float(v)
         self.weight = float(w)
     def getName(self):
         return self.name
     def getValue(self):
         return self.value
     def getWeight(self):
         return self.weight
     def __str__(self):
         return '<' + self.name + ', ' + str(self.value) + ', '\
                    + str(self.weight) + '>'


def buildItems():
    return [Item(n,v,w) for n,v,w in (('clock', 175, 10),
                                      ('painting', 90, 9),
                                      ('radio', 20, 4),
                                      ('vase', 50, 2),
                                      ('book', 10, 1),
                                      ('computer', 200, 20))]
```

***EDIT*** (rest of code)

```
def yieldAllCombos(items):
    N = len(items)
    # Enumerate the 3**N possible combinations
    for i in range(3**N):
        bag1 = []
        bag2 = []
        for j in range(N):
            if (i // (3 ** j)) % 3 == 1:
                bag1.append(items[j])
            elif (i // (3 ** j)) % 3 == 2:
                bag2.append(items[j])
        yield (bag1, bag2)
```

***Edit*** end

These are the parts of a introductory knapsack problem I've been working on, this problem made me realize I didn't understand what is really going on with classes and object instances.

If I understand `buildItems()`, it will create 6 different instances of the `Item` class and return a list containing those instances.

Trying to do something simple, I want to create that single list containing those default values in the `buildItems()` function. Just to test I do this:

```
myitems = buildItems()
print(myitems)
```

I'm expecting to see a list of lists like this:

```
[[clock,175,10], [painting,90,9], [radio,20,4], [vase, 50, 2], [book, 10, 1], [computer, 200, 20]]
```

What I get back though is:

```
[[<__main__.Item object at 0x7f2ce7819650>, <__main__.Item object at 0x7f2ce67cfa90>, <__main__.Item object at 0x7f2ceb766a50>, <__main__.Item object at 0x7f2ceb766d10>, <__main__.Item object at 0x7f2cebc9ba90>, <__main__.Item object at 0x7f2ceb4ec210>]]
```

Which I realize are the actual objects and there locations in memory, correct? What do I need to do return the actual data? Also, I have tried putting both `buildItems` inside and outside the class definition, if I put it inside, it requires me to include the `self` in the `def buildItems(self)`, but then more confusing for me, if I do this:

items = Item.buildItems()

I get:

```
TypeError: buildItems() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

It was my understanding that 'self' was always implied. If I do this:

```
items = Item.buildItems(self)
```

it returns an `"error 'self' is undefined"` obviously.

I'm just very confused, I can't seem to figure out what is different about this example and when I was learning about classes originally.

Any help guiding me through this would be greatly appreciated, I feel like it would unlock a lot conceptually for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: It's like how in C++ you need to override `<<` to tell it how to print. In Python, you need to define the class's `__repr__` instead of `__str__`. You're doing it fine, it's just printing the default representation instead of pretty printing. You could also use a `dataclass` or `NamedTuple` to automatically get pretty-printing for your class.

Comment: If your objects are stored in a list then `myitems[0].name` will return the name value of the first object in the list so clock

Comment: You are seeing "the actual data". There is nothing special here, other than your class not implementing any `__repr__` method, so it uses the default one.

Comment: You should ask yourself **why** are you expecting to see a list of lists, `[[clock,175,10], [painting,90,9], [radio,20,4], [vase, 50, 2], [book, 10, 1], [computer, 200, 20]]` when you seem to understand that you haven't created any `list` objects, rather, you created `Item` objects.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, I realized I was probably missing something simple, which is why I was misunderstanding my output. I didn't realize the proper way to call `__str__` method in the class, for `str` output.

Comment: yes, I guess I was misunderstanding the code in general, (its MITx's code for a problem exercise), the **why** is important I realize, which was what I wanted to understand, `Item` objects vs `list` objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to consider here:

1. your function `buildItems`is not part of your `Item` class. That means calling `Item.buildItems()` doenst work. This should give the error `AttributeError: type object 'Item' has no attribute 'buildItems'`. Your provided error message is probably due to the fact that the indentation is actually different?
2. your function `__str__(self)` will be called if you actually convert your items into string as follow:

   ```
   myitems = buildItems()
   print(str(myitems[0])) # results in '<clock, 175.0, 10.0>'
   ```
3. However you are calling print to the list of objects and there the `__repr__(self)` function will be used to generate a string for each of your elements inside the list. Thus you need to override the `__repr__(self)` function as follows:

   ```
   class Item(object): 
         def __init__(self, n, v, w): 
             self.name = n 
             self.value = float(v) 
             self.weight = float(w) 
         def getName(self): 
             return self.name 
         def getValue(self): 
             return self.value 
         def getWeight(self): 
             return self.weight 
         def __str__(self): 
             return '<' + self.name + ', ' + str(self.value) + ', '\ 
                        + str(self.weight) + '>' 
         def __repr__(self): 
             return str([self.name, self.value,self.weight])
   ```

**EDIT:**

This would produce the output as you wanted. However this disagrees with the intention behind the `__repr__` function as mentioned in the comment by @ShadowRanger. A better way to achieve an ouptut which could by copy pasted into the terminal is as follows:

```
def __repr__(self): 
    return self.__class__.__name__+ repr((self.name, self.value,self.weight))
```

`

Comment: Note: This is a *terrrible* `__repr__` implementation. When at all possible, the `repr` should be something you could paste into the terminal to recreate the class. [See the canonical subclass-friendly version here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44342081/364696). The OP should not be trying to make a `list` of `Item`s look like a `list` of `list`s in the first place; if that's what they need, then don't convert to `Item` in the first place, or convert back to `list` on demand.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah thank you for the explanation! Happy to have learned something again. So the correct way would be `self.__class__.__name__+ repr((self.name, self.value,self.weight))` ? Almost the same as the third version of ChrisDoyle's answer?
`

Comment: this has all been very helpful, I actually didn't write any of this code, I'm taking the MITx python course on Edx and this is their code from one of their problem exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Your already on your way and have already defined a `__str__(self)` method. This overrides the default object `__str__` method. So any time you print the item it will print in the format you have defined, infact any time you try to use your class in a stringwise fashion it will call this method.

However when you have them in a list and print the list, the object represenation will call the `__repr__` method. This is normally meant to be a representation of how to create this instance but can be anything you like it to be.

if you want to just return your same string representation you can just do

```
 def __repr__(self):
     return self.__str__()
```

if you want your output to be as you showed in your question to look like a list

```
 def __repr__(self):
     return str([self.name, self.value, self.weight])
```

if you want to represent your class as it was constructed

```
 def __repr__(self):
     return self.__class__.__name__ + "(" + ",".join((self.name, str(self.value), str(self.weight))) + ")"
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
[<clock, 175.0, 10.0>, <painting, 90.0, 9.0>, <radio, 20.0, 4.0>, <vase, 50.0, 2.0>, <book, 10.0, 1.0>, <computer, 200.0, 20.0>]
[[clock,175.0,10.0], [painting,90.0,9.0], [radio,20.0,4.0], [vase,50.0,2.0], [book,10.0,1.0], [computer,200.0,20.0]]
[Item(clock,175.0,10.0), Item(painting,90.0,9.0), Item(radio,20.0,4.0), Item(vase,50.0,2.0), Item(book,10.0,1.0), Item(computer,200.0,20.0)]
```

So you need to override the `__repr__` method but how it presents itself is really up to you.

Comment: Note: If you want the `repr` and `str` form to be identical, don't implement `__repr__` in terms of `__str__`, just implement *only* `__repr__`; the default `__str__` implementation inherited from `object` automatically uses the `__repr__` for you as long as you don't override it.

Answer (score 0):

A section of your question ask's how to develop code like below

```
myitems = buildItems()
print(myitems)
```

to generate an output like below

```
[[clock,175,10],
[painting,90,9], 
[radio,20,4], 
[vase, 50, 2], 
[book, 10, 1], 
[computer, 200, 20]]
```

---

Below is a code snip that would generate similar output.

```
myitems = buildItems()
for i in range(len(myitems)):
    print(str(myitems[i]))
```

---

Output using `__str__` define in the `Item` object

```
<clock, 175.0, 10.0>
<painting, 90.0, 9.0>
<radio, 20.0, 4.0>
<vase, 50.0, 2.0>
<book, 10.0, 1.0>
<computer, 200.0, 20.0>
```

---

**Reference:**

- [too many values to unpack in a yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310837/too-many-values-to-unpack-in-a-yield)